# Use FilePond with Dynamic Import and Code Splitting

Tags: webpack, es6-promise, filepond

I would like to load FilePond core including needed plugins only if they are really used on the page. I thought using [Webpack Dynamic Imports](https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports).

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/filepond-lazy-load-example-josspz

Doing this I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: plugin is not a function
```

The relevant code:

```
Promise.all([
  import(
    /* webpackChunkName: 'FilePondPluginFileValidateSize' */ "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size"
  ),
  import(
    /* webpackChunkName: 'FilePondPluginFileValidateType' */ "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type"
  ),
  import(
    /* webpackChunkName: 'FilePondPluginFileEncode' */ "filepond-plugin-file-encode"
  ),
  import(/* webpackChunkName: 'FilePond' */ "filepond")
]).then(
  ([
    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
    FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
    FilePondPluginFileEncode,
    FilePond
  ]) => {
    FilePond.registerPlugin(
      FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
      FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
      FilePondPluginFileEncode
    );

    // Create a FilePond instance
    FilePond.create(input, {});
  }
);
```

Error caused by this line:
https://codesandbox.io/s/filepond-lazy-load-example-josspz?file=/src/components/file-upload.js:959-992

Not really sure if it's a problem with the plugin or if I overlooked something.

Update: Fixed and working solution provided in link above.

Comment: Please paste your actual code into the question; don't just link to it externally :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the `default` property as the plugin uses default export.

In these situations the best course of action is to `console.log` variables to see what is inside.

Working version: https://codesandbox.io/s/filepond-lazy-load-example-forked-gvxrom?file=/src/components/file-upload.js